# Cant log out from facebook when simulator is stopped after a log in iphone simulator

Tags: iphone, facebook

I have integrated facebook in my iphone app.Once i log in and stop the simulator and then i call the [facebook logout] it doesnot log out.

Comment: But.. the simulator is stopped. Doesn't that prevent the app in the simulator from proceeding?

Comment: Maybe OP meant "stopped & restarted".

Answer (score 1):

Have u cleared your fbsession in logout by making all your nsuserdefault values to nill.Then one thing is there,You are loging in the the saffari browser and which is something outside our application scope.we cant do anything about that,or else you can give saffari auth to No in the facebook class.or else You have to clear Your saffari browser in the simulator by clearing all the cache values.then it will be ok.